# Latex Error “log file not found”

Tags: texmaker

Same problem as Rachelle's of Aug. 11:

I am using TeXMaker with MikTeX on Windows 7. Had to reinstall MikTeX. Previous programs work fine on the new installation. New ones I write, don't. The error message is `log file not found`. I tried the following:

1. Taking an old minimal program that works, called `test1.tex`, I copied it and called the new instance `test2.tex`. The copy generates the same complaint: `No log file`.
2. I also copied `test1.log` to `test2.log` (creating it in the process) and edited internal references from `test1` to `test2`. Result: No complaint about a missing log file, but the pdf file is not created.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Most appreciated would be an explanation of the source of the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What happens if you try `pdflatex test1` from the Command line?

Comment: Have you tried compiling without TeXMaker using the cmd?

Comment: latex itself doesn't search for the log-file. Probably texmaker is looking for the log, e.g. to generate some internal error list. So at first you must find out if texmaker doesn't find because it doesn't exist (e.g. because you killed latex before it could write it) or because texmaker looks at the wrong place.

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113433/unable-to-compile-texmaker-4-0-2-with-miktex-2-9/113680#113680