# Log file not found

Tags: errors, texstudio

I've started working with latex a few weeks ago, and it's been working fine. When today I wanted to edit my file and suddenly I got the error: `Log file not found`. 
Of course I searched if this question was already answered but usually it was for people who just reinstalled Texstudio, not that it just stopped working suddenly.

I hope somebody knows how to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)
The suggestions posted as comments to this one will probably help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67292. If you have a copy of your file before the recent changes, can you still compile that? Or any other file? Chances are that there is some error(s) in your `tex` file and TeXStudio cannot cope. Hence we cannot help without seeing your attempts to identify and fix the error in your code, in the form of an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Compiling via the command line should reveal those errors more reliably.

Comment: Solution here: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/614/

Comment: @PatrickT's solution didn't work for me. I was able to solve this problem by removing a period `.` from my `.tex` file name. Apparently, that's a no-no.

Comment: Just change your filename so that it does not contain any incorrect extensions, dots etc. make it a simple filename and let us know what happens. It solved for me.

Answer (score -1):

The log file is created when running LaTeX, so if this is an error (the processing stops) or if it persists if you run LaTeX again, show your output.